# Dynamically create objects based on a runtime count value - C#

Tags: c#

Simple example of scenario I am trying to implement

```
class ATest
{
    int a;
    int b;
    BTest[];
}

class BTest
{
    int X;
    int Y;
}
```

- I need to create `ATest` and `BTest` dynamically based on a value.
- I tried it as `Atest[] aobj = new Atest[count];` (This count value will be set programmatically)
- Now I need to create Array of Objects of `B` dynamically and assign it to `A`
- Currently I assume static value for count and assigned it

  ```
  Atest[] aobj = new Atest[20];   
  BTest[] bobj = new BTest[1];
  bobj[0] = new Btest();
  aobj[0] = new ATest();
  aobj[0].BTest = bobj;
  BTest[] bobj1 = new BTest[1];
  bobj1[0] = new Btest();
  aobj1[0].BTest = bobj1;
  ```

This may not be the best way to code.

Please suggest on dynamically implementing it
- Dynamically create number of `BTest` object arrays and assign it for `ATest` instances

Comment: What about resetting capacity of Array(BTest or ATest) within Count setter?

Comment: If I use below class approach i think it would solve the purpose to dynamically create Atest and Btest objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using constructors:

```
class ATest {
    int a;
    int b;
    BTest[] btests;
    public ATest(int numOfB) {
        btests = new BTest[numOfB];
    }
}
```

The you can create and initialize your atests in a simple loop:

```
int M = 20; // Number of Test A objects
int N = 10; // Number of Test B objects per Test A
var atests = new ATest[M];
for (var i = 0 ; i != M ; i++) {
    atests[i] = new ATest(N);
}
```